# Add font sizes options to TinyMCE editor

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

What's the easiest way to add font sizes options to Plone 4's TinyMCE editor?

For some reason a client has this request.

In Site Setup - TinyMCE Visual Editor - Toolbar I can't see any option related to this feature.

This is how it looks in my application:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/portal_tinymce/@@tinymce-controlpanel` - `Styles` add definitions:

```
Font size 8|span|custom-font-size-8
Font size 9|span|custom-font-size-9
Font size 10|span|custom-font-size-10
```

etc.
Meaning you can select the options Font size x in your editor. This will be saved as a span with class `custom-font-size-x`.

When you save this it will already work. But you need the styles to make this visible.
I had an override to tinymce editor already set so I added the styles for each class like:

```
.custom-font-size-10 {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

in `content.css.dtml` file. Also add this css in your theme to see the effect in view mode.